# try/catch block not catching async/await error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async.js

I have a simple `timeout` function which wraps an async function with a timeout to ensure that it fails after a preset amount of time. The timeout function is as follows:

```
export default async function<T = any>(
  fn: Promise<T>,
  ms: number,
  identifier: string = ""
): Promise<T> {
  let completed = false;
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (completed === false) {
      const e = new Error(`Timed out after ${ms}ms [ ${identifier} ]`);
      e.name = "TimeoutError";
      throw e;
    }
  }, ms);
  const results = await fn;
  completed = true;
timer.unref();

  return results;
}
```

I then use this function in this simple code snippet to ensure that the **fetch** request (using `node-fetch` implementation) is converted into a text output:

```
let htmlContent: string;
  try {
    htmlContent = await timeout<string>(
      response.text(),
      3000,
      `waiting for text conversion of network payload`
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(
      chalk.grey(`- Network response couldn\'t be converted to text: ${e.message}`)
    );
    problemsCaching.push(business);
    return business;
  }
```

When running this code over many iterations, most URL endpoints provide a payload that can be easily converted to text but occasionally one crops up which seems to just hang the **fetch** call. In these case the timeout does in fact trigger but the `TimeoutError` that is thrown is NOT caught by the catch block but instead terminates the running program.

I'm a bit baffled. I do use async/await a lot now but I may still have a few rough edges in my understanding. Can anyone explain how I can effectively capture this error and handle it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A thrown error will only be caught if its *directly enclosing function* has some sort of error handling. Your anonymous function passed to `setTimeout` is not the `async` function itself, so the `async` function won't stop executing if the *separate* `timeout` throws after some time:

```js
const makeProm = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 200));
(async () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error();
  }, 200);
  await makeProm();
  console.log('done');
})()
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('caught');
  });
```

This looks like a good time to use `Promise.race`: pass it the `fetch` `Promise`, and also pass it a `Promise` that rejects after the passed `ms` parameter:

```js
async function timeout(prom, ms) {
  return Promise.race([
    prom,
    new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => rej('timeout!'), ms))
  ])
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await timeout(
      new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 2000)),
      500
    )
   } catch(e) {
      console.log('err ' + e);
   }
})();
```

Comment: How to catch an error like this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885850/how-to-catch-the-following-error-failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url

Answer (score 2):

This error is happening in a separate call stack, because it's thrown from within a callback.  It's totally separate from the synchronous execution flow inside the `try` / `catch` block.

You want to manipulate the same promise object from within the timeout or the success callback.  Something like this should work better:

```
return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
    let rejected = false;
    const timer = setTimeout( () => {
        rejected = true;
        reject( new Error( 'Timed out' ) );
    }, ms ).unref();
    fn.then( result => {
        clearTimeout( timer );
        if ( ! rejected ) {
            resolve( result ) );
        }
    } );
} );
```

It would probably work just fine without the `rejected` and `clearTimeout` too, but this way you ensure that either `resolve` or `reject` is called, not both.

You'll notice that I didn't use `await` or `throw` anywhere here!  If you are having trouble with asynchronous code, it is better to write it using a single style first (all callbacks, or all promises, or all "synchronous" style using `await`).

This example in particular **cannot** be written using only `await`, because you need to have two tasks running at the same time (the timeout and the request).  You could probably use [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), but you still need a `Promise` to work with.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that async/await allowed the capture of both sync and async errors within a try/catch block? Let me give this a try, I do get your point about keeping to a single style though and maybe I'm misinterpreting your use of "synchronous flow" from above.

Comment: "I thought that async/await allowed the capture of both sync and async errors within a try/catch block?"  Not really.. using `await` is what I mean by "synchronous flow".  Probably not the best term, but code written in this style that does not branch out into separate callbacks will execute in the order it is written, and it will work with `try` / `catch`.  As soon as you need to start and manage multiple tasks at once, things get more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide some general rule as the answer was already given.

> Try/catch is by default synchronous. That means that if an
>   asynchronous function throws an error in a synchronous try/catch
>   block, no error throws.