# Why my try catch block didn't catch the fs.renameSync exception thrown by my Promise.promisifyAll object

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise, try-catch, bluebird

The code is quite straightforward. [ks3 is a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ks3) someone else developed. It has a start function to download files. It uses `async.auto` to do that.
I wrap it with bluebird `Promise.promisifyAll`

```
let ks3p = Promise.promisifyAll(ks3) //ks3 has a start function
try {
    await ks3p.startAsync(param)
} catch (err) {
    //failed to catch fs.renameSync
}
```

But sometimes I get the error

```
fs.js:115
    throw err;
    ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename ... -> ...
    at Object.renameSync (fs.js:591:3)
```

So why the try catch block failed to catch that ?

I further checked [the start() implementation](https://github.com/ks3sdk/ks3-nodejs-sdk/blob/master/lib/api/download.js). It uses [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to download files, but nothing special.

```
async.auto({
    step_1 : ...
    step_2 : ...
    },
    function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        if (cb) {
            cb(err, results)
        } else {
            fs.unlinkSync(configFile);
            throw err;
        }
    } else {
        fs.unlinkSync(configFile);
        fs.renameSync(downFileName, filePath);
        if (cb) {
            cb(err, {msg:'success',path:filePath}, null);
        }
    }
})
```

------ update -------

Part of reason I wrap with Promise.promisifyAll is I do not know how to catch that error. My original code was like this

```
ks3.download.start(param, (err, result) => {
    //But how do I catch the exception start throw asynchronously ?
    if (err) {
        // error handling 
    } else {
        log(`finished download ${file}`)
    }
    done()
})
```

------ update2 -------

After further digging the issue (the answer is helpful) I find either I modified ks3 codes or I will have to use domain to catch the exception. I know [domain is deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html). But for this specific issue I find it is appropriate b/c I know exactly what causes the problem and I also don't fix that problem at the moment(b/c it is a npm module I have no control).

Comment: Why, in the world are you using the async library here?  It's such a mess to mix plain callbacks with promises.  Error handling is a nightmare (and thus your problem).

Comment: That is someone else's code (the ks3.start function) and I wrap it inside Promise.promisifyAll

Comment: But even I didn't wrap ks3.start with Promise.promisifyAll and used the old err callback I still don't know how to catch that error.

Comment: Too much missing code here.  Can't follow the flow of control in the code.  Don't know what `ks3p.startAsync()` has to do with `async.auto()` at all.  Sorry, just not enough info here to know what this is doing or to follow the code to offer advice.  Also, don't know what ks3 is at all.  It looks to me like you should be catching errors inside of your callback function and then calling `cb(err)` if there's an error, but that's just a wild guess because there's so much missing code.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. I updated my question, can you please check it again ?

Comment: Hi I also added the link to start()  https://github.com/ks3sdk/ks3-nodejs-sdk/blob/master/lib/api/download.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [try/catch block not catching async/await error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197194/try-catch-block-not-catching-async-await-error) for some additional context, but to answer your question about how to catch the error in the ***un***-promisified version, you have to understand the call stack when the error is thrown.

You had

```
ks3.download.start(param, (err, result) => {
    //But how do I catch the exception start throw asynchronously ?
    if (err) {
        // error handling 
    } else {
        log(`finished download ${file}`)
    }
    done()
})
```

which you should think of as:

```
var cb = (err, result) => {
    //But how do I catch the exception start throw asynchronously ?
    if (err) {
        // error handling 
    } else {
        log(`finished download ${file}`)
    }
    done()
});

ks3.download.start(param, cb);
```

and it's `start` itself that's throwing the exception (way before it gets around to calling or scheduling your callback), so you'd need to wrap *that* call in a try-catch:

```
var cb = (err, result) => {
    //But how do I catch the exception start throw asynchronously ?
    if (err) {
        // error handling 
    } else {
        log(`finished download ${file}`)
    }
    done()
});

try {
    ks3.download.start(param, cb);
} catch (ex) {
    // here.
}
```

I'm a little suspicious of `async.auto`'s exception-handling, though, and i fear it might be running something throwing asynchronously without catching errors. In particular, it doesn't look like it expects the `callback` function to ever *throw* (see https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/auto.js), but https://github.com/ks3sdk/ks3-nodejs-sdk/blob/master/lib/api/download.js *does* throw if the `fs` methods fail, like you're seeing.

As such, there's nothing you can do other than a) fix `ks3` or b) *maybe* find a way to monkey-patch the version of `fs` that `ks3` sees to never throw. Of the two, (a) sounds a lot easier to me and i think it should look something like this:

```
async.auto({
    // ...
}, 
function(err, results) {
    if (cb) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err);
            return;
        }
        try {
            fs.unlinkSync(configFile);
            fs.renameSync(downFileName, filePath);
        } catch (ex) {
            cb(ex);
            return;
        }
        cb(err, {msg:'success', path:filePath}, null);
    } else {
        // really, i wouldn't even bother fix this case and just make cb required.
    }
})
```

On top of that, i'm assuming it's a bug that the `ks3` code doesn't delete the config file if there's an error *and* there's a callback.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering my question. I tried to catch the error in the un-promisified version as you suggested. But I still failed to catch it. I added another catcher process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.error('Error caught in uncaughtException event:', err)
})  . I found it is that one catch the renameSync error.

Comment: But I then realized that would not catch the exception b/c ks3.start() throws the exception asynchronously.

Comment: Hi I come to the conclusion that if I don't fix k3 I will have to use domain, deprecated I know, to catch fs exception.

Comment: Good luck! Ks3 looks like it hasn't been updated in over a year. You might have to fork it.