# How to catch the following error "Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL':"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I am using Nextjs (irrelevant but still).
I have tried using the trycatch block and unable to catch the above error. Is there a way to catch this error. If so how can it be done.

Try/catch block cannot catch this error.

**This happens when the url is `invalid (meaning the object to which the url is pointing doesn't exist or has been deleted)` for some reason**

Following is the code :-

```js
function saveOrOpenBlob(url, blobName, changeName) {
    try {
      if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      }
      let blob;
      let xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHTTP.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlHTTP.responseType = "arraybuffer";
      xmlHTTP.onload = function (e) {
        blob = new Blob([this.response]);
      };
      xmlHTTP.onprogress = function (pr) {
        //pr.loaded - current state
        //pr.total  - max
        setDownloadProgress((pr.loaded / pr.total) * 100);
      };
      xmlHTTP.onloadend = function (e) {
        let fileName = blobName;
        let tempEl = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(tempEl);
        tempEl.style = "display: none";
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        tempEl.href = url;
        if (changeName) {
          tempEl.download = fileName;
        }
        tempEl.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        // For the progressbar to be visible for more duration
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
          setDownloading(false);
          setDownloadProgress(0);
        }, 1000);
      };
      xmlHTTP.send();
    } catch (error) {
      setDownloading(false);
      setDownloadProgress(0);
      setAlert("An error occurred while downloading the file", "error", 4000);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to catch exceptions thrown in a JavaScript async callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3677783)

Comment: Any reason you trigger the download on `onloadend`? It's called regardless, if the request succeeds (`onload` was called) or not.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(window.URL);` just a line above the attempt to call of `createObjectURL` and tell us what the result is?

Answer (score 1):

first, you should do a null check on the blob and exit the function if it is null or do some other logic for example :

```
if(!blob) {
  setDownloading(false);
  setDownloadProgress(0);
  setAlert("An error occurred while downloading the file", "error", 4000);
  return;
}
```

and second, the try catch is not detecting the error because it is not happening under the same scope.

if you want to catch the error move the try catch to the `onloadend` function

```
xmlHTTP.onloadend = function (e) {
    try {
       ...
       url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       ...
    } catch {
       ...
    }
  };
```

Comment: This answer is correct. all  `xmlHTTP.onSomething`, could be put outside  `saveOrOpenBlob` and that would still work. We should put in the mind that every function has it own scope. When we assign a function to an event like `onloadend`, that does not mean that function is running on that time, that function is going to be run by other process at the proper moment.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're experiencing may not be caught by the `try/catch` block because the error is asynchronous and originates from the event listeners of the `XMLHttpRequest` (xmlHTTP). The `try/catch` block only captures synchronous errors within its scope. For asynchronous errors, you need to handle them within the context they occur.

To catch the error you're experiencing when the URL is invalid, you should listen to the `onerror` event of the `xmlHTTP` object. Here's how you can do it:

- Add an `onerror` event listener to your xmlHTTP object.
- Handle the error within this event listener.

Here's a modification to your code:

```
function saveOrOpenBlob(url, blobName, changeName) {
    try {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        let blob;
        let xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHTTP.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHTTP.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        xmlHTTP.onload = function(e) {
            blob = new Blob([this.response]);
        };
        xmlHTTP.onprogress = function(pr) {
            //pr.loaded - current state 
            //pr.total - max 
            setDownloadProgress((pr.loaded / pr.total) * 100);
        };
        // Handle errors here 
        xmlHTTP.onerror = function(e) {
            setDownloading(false);
            setDownloadProgress(0);
            setAlert("An error occurred while downloading the file", "error", 4000);
        };
        xmlHTTP.onloadend = function(e) {
            if (blob) {
                let fileName = blobName;
                let tempEl = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(tempEl);
                tempEl.style = "display: none";
                url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                tempEl.href = url;
                if (changeName) {
                    tempEl.download = fileName;
                }
                tempEl.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                // For the progressbar to be visible for more duration 
                timer = setTimeout(() => {
                    setDownloading(false);
                    setDownloadProgress(0);
                }, 1000);
            }
        };
        xmlHTTP.send();
    } catch (error) {
        setDownloading(false);
        setDownloadProgress(0);
        setAlert("An error occurred while setting up the download", "error", 4000);
    }
}
```

In this modified version, the `onerror` event listener has been added to handle errors related to the `XMLHttpRequest`. This should enable you to catch the error when the URL is invalid.